# Copying EC2 AMI from one region to another in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am quite new to AWS and I am doing everything through the console which has worked out pretty great so far.

I now need to copy an AMI from one region to another, however, the AWS documentation seems to be a little outdated.

This is what I have read:

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/ec2-ami-copy-between-regions/

On the site it says that there is the option "Destination Regio" when creating the snapshot but this is not the case.

Anyone who can recommend a good read on the subject?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The article you referred to is more than clear (and does not mention 'option "Destination Region" when creating the snapshot').

You go to your source region, choose EC2 console, AMI view, select the AMI that you want to copy, then you will get to choose the Destination region.

Comment: Don't know how i missed that. Thanks a lot for taking the time!